# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. error in Angular 5 app

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I just started learning angular 5. Now I got the below error

> Failed to compile.
>
> ```
> ./src/app/route/app.routing.ts
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:28)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
> | var appRoutes = [
> |     { path: '', component:  }
> | ];
> | 
>  @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 11:20-50
>  @ ./src/main.ts
>  @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
> ```

### And my app.routing.ts file

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ProductListComponent } from '../product-list/product-list.component';

const appRoutes : Routes = [

    {path: '', component: ProductListComponent, pathMatch:'full'},
    {path:'product-list', component: ProductListComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I couldn't find out what does the error really mean.Please help

Comment: Can you post `ProductListComponent` code?

Answer (score 0):

try redirectTo

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [

    {path: '', redirectTo: '/product-list', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path:'product-list', component: ProductListComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}

];
```

Comment: Now its working , I restarted the server, Server takes much time to detect changes